# Computer Graphics-related Tasks Involving The "Smallest-circle problem"

Tags: algorithm, geometry, pyhook

I have two tasks related to the "Smallest-circle problem":

1. Implement a one-pass algorithm that calculates an enclosing circle for a generic set of 2D points.
2. Define a set of 2D points *Q* for the algorithm, which returns an enclosing circle bigger than the minimum one.

I've done task #1 using Welzl's algorithm; but I'm not sure I understood the second question. Are they asking me to find a way for the algorithm to break, or a limitation of the algorithm?

Comment: Re: "I've done task #1 using Welzl's algorithm": But that task asks for a one-pass algorithm, which Welzl's algorithm is not.

Comment: @ruakh I see then I completely misremember what one pass is will have a look at it, but still I dont understand the second question

Comment: The first question asks you to give a (one-pass) algorithm to find *an* enclosing circle. Notice that the algorithm doesn't have to find the smallest enclosing circle though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first task isn't asking for an algorithm to find the *smallest* enclosing circle, it's asking for an algorithm to find *an* enclosing circle. It specifies that this should be a "one-pass" algorithm, meaning that the algorithm iterates only once over the list of points.

There are many possible answers to the first task, because it doesn't put any limit on how big you're allowed to make the circle; for example, if the set contains only a single point, it would be completely valid for the algorithm to find a circle of radius 10<sup>20</sup> that includes that point. (Of course, there's no reason to go so extreme. If the radius of the smallest enclosing circle is *R*, there's a very simple one-pass algorithm to find an enclosing circle whose radius is at most *R*√2, which I'll put in a spoiler tag below so that that you can think about it first if you like.)

> Iterate over the points, keeping track of the least and greatest *x*-coordinate and the least and greatest *y*-coordinate. Return the circle with center = (½(*x*<sub>min</sub> + *x*<sub>max</sub>), ½(*y*<sub>min</sub> + *y*<sub>max</sub>)) and radius = ½√((*x*<sub>max</sub> − *x*<sub>min</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*y*<sub>max</sub> − *y*<sub>min</sub>)<sup>2</sup>).

The second task depends on your answer to the first task. Since your algorithm presumably does *not* find the smallest enclosing circle for all sets of points (since we don't know of any one-pass algorithm that does so), the second task is just to find a set of points for which your algorithm returns a larger circle than necessary. For example, if for task #1 you use the algorithm described in the spoiler above, then for task #2 you could give

> The set {(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)}: the smallest enclosing circle has radius 1, but the above algorithm gives a circle of radius √2.

Comment: ah I see how it is this was my first approach to the issue, but I thought they where asking for the "Smallest-circle"